# How to reconfigure VSCode for python

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I had configured VSCode for python, it was working fine, linter , autopep all the things were working fine. After some days I installed Anaconda, from here problems started, after this I got error that Select Python Interpreter at the bottom of VSCode, I added python path to the settings,then it works fine but "Select Python Interpreter" error was still coming. Some days before I installed Javascript extension, after this linter,autopep nothing is working,only using python command line python program is getting run.
I removed javascript extension,again installed VSCode, now the things are worst,nothing is working now.Please anyone help me to how to reconfigure VSCode to work properly.Even I removed Anaconda installation too, still problems not solved. I searched online but did not get any proper inforamtion.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I think you have both Python 3.7  and Anaconda installed separately, Use any one them , remove the other. When both of them is together it was throwing lot of issues. I would prefer to remove Anaconda(pure personal choice).If you don't have much customized settings in VScode, delete its user configuration files and set it up again. it will work

Comment: Tried, but same error Select Python Interpreter is comig,pylint, autopep not working

Comment: Can you tell me what you did, deleted anaconda, did you delete config files of VSCODE, ? Last  resort if nothing else works: Just uninstall it and reinstall VScode, delete .vscode folder(sometimes hidden)  i‪n C:\Users\username\

Comment: I uninstalled Anaconda,after that deleted its file,wherever present.For VSCode,first i uninstalled all extensions which i installed,then uninstalled VSCode,after this ,I accessed .code file using %APPDATA%,deleted this folder,then deleted .vscode dir which contains all extensions.from c drive,still problem persist.Thinking to install new os and only install VSCode no Anaconda.All the things because of Anaconda installation , before that all the things were fine.

Comment: Installing OS again is an extreme step for this issue, Check for restore options.

Comment: Yesterday I tried with windows restore ,but still problem is there, actually it is my fault I did not created restore point when i formatted my laptop,because of that that it restored to 2 days before state,the same issues were there but pylint and autopep was working,after javascript extension installation it stopped working, yesterday i thought to resolve issues, but now things are completely messed up. nw issues are pylint and autopep is not woking, I have to format code it manualy,stil that select python interpeter eror is comng,now i run type code in VSCode itself and run on Command line.